# How to visualize axis-aligned boxes with ParaView

Tags: vtk, paraview

I would like to visualize a number of axis-aligned bounding boxes in ParaView. I will create an unstructured grid and insert `vtkVoxel` cells in there. How many points should each voxel be associated with? Since the documentation says voxels are efficient in storage, I thought two corners would be enough, but [this post](http://www.vtk.org/pipermail/vtkusers/2008-May/095426.html), for example, seems to be setting 8 for each of them. I was not able to get anything from the documentation either.